# Get top 5 foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have a table say City. I have state as a foreign key in it. What query I need to write to get the `Top 5` states which occur in the city table.

Eg

```
Id City       State
1  Mumbai     Maharashtra
2  Pune       Maharashtra
3  Amritsar   Punjab
```

Here the output I expect is to get as names of the states with count

```
State_Name   count
Maharashtra  2
Punjab       1


SELECT p.name, count(pr.State) FROM City pr
join state p on p.Id = pr.StateId;
```

Comment: Why isn't what you have written working, where is your sql query

Comment: @TobyAllen Pls see my edit with the code that I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Group by` with `count` aggregate to count the `state` and use `Limit` to filter the records

```
select count(1) Cnt,state 
from yourtable
group by state
order by Cnt desc Limit 5
```